# Two Custom tableviewcell height on the basis of content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen many questions and answers about this question but nothing is working. I have two custom Cell in a tablview. I want to change the height of cell on the basis of content.I am try to use this code right now but its never work.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)hospital.hospComment.count);
    if (hospital.hospComment.count > (indexPath.row+1)) {
        cell.personComment.text = [hospital.hospComment objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row +1)];

    }

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    height += 1;

    return height;
}
```

How I can achieve that ??

Comment: Check this example - https://github.com/rayfix/MultilineDemo

Comment: Your `*cell` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare cell like,

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableViewCellMain"];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tableViewCellMain"];

}
```

Accordint to your declaration cell will be nil. second thing make sure you are giving proper constraints

And another suggestion : you can use apple's new feature `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `estimatedRowHeight`. To know more about it refer this greate and little tutorial from [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you cell have right constraints ? If not , this code will never work.Because apple cannot caculate your cell height

Answer (score 0):

If you are using supporting iOS 8 and above there is no need to calculate height for each row, if you have set the constraints in your cell correctly.

You need include the following lines in `viewDidLoad` :

```
[self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
[self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:45.0];
```

If you are supporting versions less iOS 8, you need to calculate the height manually for each row. You have plenty of tutorial for calculating the height of cell.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple project and faced the same problem, so I kept a method for calculating the height of cell in customTavleViewCell, here is what I did lets keep the tableview as 
tableview.h and tableview.m files and CustomTableViewCell.h and CustomTableViewCell.m
In tableview.h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *tempViewController;
```

In tableview.h (heightforrowatindex path)

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]init];
_tempViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[_tempViewController.view addSubview:cell];
if(hospital.hospComment.count > (indexPath.row+1)) {
{
    cell.personComment.text = [hospital.hospComment objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row +1)];
}return [cell calcheight];}
```

in CustomTableViewCell.h

```
-(CGFloat)calcheight;
```

in CustomTableViewCell.m

```
-(CGFloat)calcheight{
CGFloat height;
// do calculations using the text in personComment
return height;}
```

And if you have any problem or have any doubts comment below

Kind Regards

Koushik S